# Twitter API app-only authorization error

Tags: twitter

I am following this https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only

```
def get_bearer_token(self):
    data = {"grant_type": "client_credentials"}
    headers = {"Authorization": "Basic " + self.encoded_cred}
    r = requests.post("https://api.twitter.com/oauth2/token",
                      data=data, headers=headers)
    res = r.json()
    if res.get('token_type') != 'bearer':
        raise Exception("invalid type")
    self.access_token = res['access_token']

def search(self, q):

    data = {"count": 100, "q": q}
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + self.access_token}
    r = requests.get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json", data=data, headers=headers)
    print r.status_code
    print r.text
```

I was able to get an access_token but the search API call returns 400 with no content. Any idea?

Similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102409/twitter-application-only-auth-returning-empty-response  but no answer yet